# Linear Equation to Matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Hey everyone I'm practicing some linear equation matrix questions, so far they're easy to construct, but I am completely lost on this one since I cannot use the method of putting them in separate columns like the normal technique used. Where do I start with this question, please anyone give me guidance?

(a) Consider the system of linear equations given by

$_1 = −x_2$

$200 x_3 = 200$

$x_3 = 4 − 3 x_4$

$100 x_2 + 100 x_3 = 100$

(i) Write the above system of equations in matrix form.

Comment: So basically, the first column of your matrix corresponds to the coefficients of the $x_1$ variable. So it would look like $[1, 0, 0, 0]$ as the first _column_. Same for second, third, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $1x_1 +(-1)x_2 + 0x_3 + 0x_4 = 0$ for the first row (that is $(1, -1, 0, 0)$), $0x_1 +0x_2 + 200x_3 + 0x_4 = 200$ for the second, $0x_1 +0x_2 + 1x_3 + 3x_4 = 4$ for the third, and $0x_1 +100x_2 + 100x_3 + 0x_4 = 100$ for the last.

Comment: you should align your equations to make them resemble a matrix. `\begin{align}...\end{align}`

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to `Math.SE`. I hope you are not asking your HW question.

You can collate all the variables to one-side and constants to the other as

$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0&0\\0&0&200&0\\0&0&1&3\\0&100&100&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\200\\4\\100\end{bmatrix},$

thereby, forming a set of linear equation in a matrix form $Ax=b.$